# python:IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. When I tried google-analytics-api sample code

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get data from google-analytics-api, I run the sample code:HelloAnalytics.py(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py),
but there are some error:IOError: [Errno 13]
I had added my service account email address to my GA account
I am using mac os.

detail error message:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/python-f/HelloAnalytics.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/python-f/HelloAnalytics.py", line 77, in main
    analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/python-f/HelloAnalytics.py", line 34, in initialize_analyticsreporting
    analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 222, in build
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 269, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/transport.py", line 159, in new_request
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 744, in _refresh
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 775, in _do_refresh_request
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1036, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 911, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 520, in __init__
    self._context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

the source code:

```
"""Hello Analytics Reporting API V4."""

import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '/Users/mac/Documents/python-f/MyProject-a7c00ebc9685.p12'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'data-510@prime-imagery-150409.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
VIEW_ID = '120100451'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an analyticsreporting service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""

  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])

    for row in rows:
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print header + ': ' + dimension

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print 'Date range (' + str(i) + ')'
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value


def main():

  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: To exclude the obvious, did you add your service account email address to your GA account ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a service account.   Did you give the service account access to your Google Analytics account?

Go to the google analytics website under admin add the service account email address at the ACCOUNT level to the account you wish to request data for.

Idea number two:

`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` check that you have permssions to the p12 file.

Comment: I added the account. It has  Read & Analyze permissions.

Comment: if it still doesn't work double check your VIEW_ID.  You don't have access to the account you are requesting data from.

Comment: I checked the VIEW_ID, it's right. The problem still exists.

Comment: Then since I am technically not a python div I would double check that your script has access to KEY_FILE_LOCATION.   I guess it could be a file access error.